# Can't make link active in UIWebView that is not user interactible

Tags: iphone, ios, webview

i have a webview in a scrollview with a lot of text in it.

The thing is that if my webview is user interactive, i can't scroll (because i can't quite get empty space to touch) but also i have some links in the webview (a href type) to some websites.

How can i make this links active but also enable good scrolling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
implement below delegate method

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView1 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{


            NSURL *requestURL = [[ request URL] retain];

            NSString *str_url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",requestURL];
            if([str_url isEqualToString:@"about:blank"]){
                [requestURL release];
                return YES;
            }else{
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
            }   
            [requestURL release];
            return NO;


    }
```